# Running mocha gives error 'ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined'

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, redux, session-storage

I am setting up Mocha for my ReactJs app (in ES6 format mostly).

On running the test using `"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register --recursive"` setup in package.json I get the following output:

```
purezen_@mb ~/workspace/webapp (Test-Setup●●)$ npm test

> webapp@0.1.0 test /Users/purezen_/workspace/webapp
> mocha --compilers js:babel-register --recursive

/Users/purezen_/workspace/webapp/src/js/data/reducers/auth.js:31
var auth = sessionStorage.getItem('auth');
           ^

ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (auth.js:5:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at loader (/Users/purezen_/workspace/kredx-fe/client/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/purezen_/workspace/webapp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at loader (/Users/purezen_/workspace/webapp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:5)
```

**test/actions/actions.spec.js**

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import sagas from 'data/sagas'
import nock from 'nock'
import expect from 'expect'

(function (glob) {
    function mockStorage() {
        var storage = {};
        return {
            setItem: function(key, value) {
                storage[key] = value || '';
            },
            getItem: function(key) {
                return storage[key];
            },
            removeItem: function(key) {
                delete storage[key];
            },
            get length () {
                return Object.keys(storage).length;
            },
            key: function(i) {
                var keys = Object.keys(storage);
                return keys[i] || null;
            }
        };
    }
    glob.localStorage = mockStorage();
    glob.sessionStorage = mockStorage();
}(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : global));

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(sagas)
const middlewares = [ sagaMiddleware ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
// const storeWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(middlewares)(mockStore)

console.log(mockStore)
```

I have tried to implement a mock session storage in the spec file, but that doesn't seem to help.

EDIT: Here's my auth.js as requested in the comments

```
import * as c from 'data/constants'
import {Map} from 'immutable'

// Load auth details from session storage
const auth = sessionStorage.getItem('auth');
const defaultState = Map(JSON.parse(auth));

export default function (state=defaultState, action) {
  const { type, payload} = action
  switch (type) {
    case c.SET_AUTH: {
      return Map(payload)
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code from /Users/purezen_/workspace/webapp/src/js/data/reducers/auth.js:31
var auth = sessionStorage.getItem('auth');

Comment: @4m1r updated in the description

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I see the problem.  You're trying to set a global sessionStorage from within your test, which is fine, but Mocha makes this easier with `before`.  This example should help you get things moving.

Here's what the spec should look like.

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import sagas from '../sagas'
import nock from 'nock'
import expect from 'expect'

describe('test the sagas', function(){

  before(function(){

    if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('window is defined');
      global = window;
    }

    function mockStorage() {
        var storage = {};
        return {
            setItem: function(key, value) {
                storage[key] = value || '';
            },
            getItem: function(key) {
                return storage[key];
            },
            removeItem: function(key) {
                delete storage[key];
            },
            get length () {
                return Object.keys(storage).length;
            },
            key: function(i) {
                var keys = Object.keys(storage);
                return keys[i] || null;
            }
        };
    }

    global['localStorage'] = mockStorage();
    global['sessionStorage'] = mockStorage();

  });

  it('should bootstrap a saga and store', function(){

    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(sagas);
    const middlewares = [ sagaMiddleware ];
    const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
    console.log('mockStore', mockStore);

  });

});
```

Notice how instead of using an IIFE, we can use `before` which is provided by Mocha.  This allows you to setup things like global.sessionStorage before the tests begin. The whole thing should be wrapped up in a `describe` and you should use `it` to identify the actual unit test.

With this bootstrapping done in the before function, your test against auth.js will probably just work.

I published this [whole example to github](https://github.com/adjavaherian/pedro), with another async_action example from another post.  You can check it out and follow the README and the two specs should work.  Good luck.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I checked out your repo and the difference is that for me the sagas module is depending upon files requiring 'sessionStorage' and 'window' objects which is why my test file is failing at the `import` command.

Comment: Hmm, can you show me what you're talking about in the sagas module dependency?

Answer (score -2):

// This should go in mocha test folder/ helpers.js

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';

// Jsdom document & window
  const doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body><div id="react-root"></div></html>');

  const win = doc.defaultView;
// Add to global
   global.document = doc;
   global.window = win;

   global.localStorage = {};

// Add window keys to global window
Object.keys(window).forEach((key) => {
if (!(key in global)) {
global[key] = window[key];
}
});
```